# Find a value with several results on different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I create this new thread in case you can help me with this macro. I am developing an excel which will be used for daily checks. This consists of two sheets, the "Home" which is where the data will be displayed, and "Data", where they are imported for processing. These are some examples of each of them ...

**Home**

[image: Sheet - Home]

**Data**

[image: Sheet - Data]

So far I have managed to import the data and format it in this way has not been easy, but what I need now is to be able to create a macro that looks for the values located in column B12: B999 (Node name) and row C11: J11 ( Type) of the Home and the Data sheet and that I returned from the "Status" column, but sometimes there may be more than one result. Please, any ideas that can help me achieve this?

This is the file -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnVp5sTfpo_IVOPgsGEQdvZnVocwAgOn/view?usp=sharing

And the code I am developing is this.

```
Sub copy2()
Dim Dn As Range, ac As Long, n As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Dic As Object, Col As Integer
Dim Ray As Variant, Txt As String, p As Variant

Ray = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:ZZ1").CurrentRegion
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For n = 1 To UBound(Ray, 1)
        Txt = Ray(n, 1) '& Ray(n, 2)
            If Not Dic.Exists(Txt) Then
                Set Dic(Txt) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            End If
            For ac = 1 To UBound(Ray, 2) Step 1
                If Not Dic(Txt).Exists(Ray(n, ac)) Then
                    Dic(Txt).Add (Ray(n, ac)), Ray(n, ac + 1)
                End If
            Next ac
    Next n

Set Rng = Sheets("Home").Range("B11").CurrentRegion
For n = 12 To Rng.Count
    With Sheets("Home")
        If Dic.Exists(.Range("B12" & n).Value) Then
            For Each p In Dic(.Range("B12" & n).Value)
                Col = Application.Match(p, Rng(1).Offset(1).Resize(, Rng.Rows.Count), 0)
                Sheets("Home").Cells(n, Col) = _
                Dic(.Range("B" & n).Value).Item(p)
            Next p
        End If
    End With
Next n

End Sub
```

But I'm stuck at the point -->

`Col = Application.Match(p, Rng(1).Offset(1).Resize(, Rng.Rows.Count), 0)`

Thanks a lot in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: This data was in a previous question some weeks ago, but can't find it right now. Anyways, about your question, MATCH is not what you need because, as you said, *sometimes there may be more than one result*. So loop trough ranges ` B12: B999`  and `C11: J11` and check each cell to get what you need

Comment: Or use the `Find` method.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you very much for your reply, I will try to use find. I will update the forum with the progress.

Regards.